# Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' in Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, json, binaryformatter

I am trying to deep clone an object using BinaryFormatter, but i am getting this error

```
Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' in Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' is not marked as serialisable
```

Can someone please help me with this ?

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClassObject
{
    public JObject RandomJobject { get; set; }
    public SheetInfo2 Clone()
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (SheetInfo2)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: There are few posts out there related to this topic, but I couldn't find any solutions. *My original class has few more properties in the class.

Comment: Why should it be?  Why would you want to serialize JObject instead of the JSON string or the original object? What are you trying to do? Don't say "I want to serialize a JObject", that's how you think you'll solve your problem. What is the *actual* problem? Why not use generics, or `dynamic` or an ExpandoObject?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Basically I am trying to achieve DeepClone of an Object. I was able to do this using **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(OriginalObject))**, But this is slow, I wanted to try using the above method to see if its any better.

Comment: doesn't explain why you use JObject at all. It's meant to be using for JSON parsing only. Anyway, if you intend to use BinaryFormatter to clone, all objects have to be serializable.

Comment: You can use [`JToken.DeepClone()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_DeepClone.htm) to deep-clone your `JObject`.  Performance should be much better than serializing and then deserializing.